CSS selector referring to the current target's parent's class
I have a DIV that will toggle an icon on a click. It has a directive toggling a class asc on it.
<div appSortable (click)="onSort('name')">
  <app-icon-sort-asc></app-icon-sort-asc>
  <span>"name"</span>
</div>

Inside the DIV, I have an icon that is supposed to stay hidden unless the DIV it's inside of (its immediate parent) gets classed as ascending by the directive mentioned above.
app-icon-sort-asc {
  display: none;
}

.asc>app-icon-sort-asc {
  display: inline;
}

Is there a way to refactor so that the both states are embraced in a single selector for the icon? Psuedo-code would be like so.
app-icon-sort-asc {
  display: none;

  [parent].asc>app-icon-sort-asc {
    display: inline;
  }
}

(Eventually, I plan to target the icon component from the DIV's directive refering to its .children[0].classList. However, I got curious if the CSS can be manipulated somehow the way described above.)
This answer appears at first related but isn't actually addressing my issue. This one may possibly be relevant. However, while reading I got mixed impressions: that it's possible but also not quite.

You can do it Like below:


app-icon-sort-asc {
  display: none;
  .asc > &  {
    display: inline;
  }
}
<div appSortable >
  <app-icon-sort-asc>icon</app-icon-sort-asc>
  <span>"name"</span>
</div>

<div appSortable class="asc">
  <app-icon-sort-asc>icon</app-icon-sort-asc>
  <span>"name"</span>
</div>




I'm a little bit confused. The solution you presented only differs from my attempt in the question by me referring to a tag <app-icon-sort-asc> while you applying &. The confusing part is that I believed (entirely possibly wrongly) that the ampersand operator referred to said tag. Could you elaborate on that part, please? I can speculate regarding the difference that it's any tag of that type in my case but that particular instance of the tag in yours. I've never heard about such distinction nor can I find any articles confirming/refuting that theory. What's your take?

@KonradViltersten https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting/#nest-selector : "When used in the selector of a nested style rule, the nesting selector represents the elements matched by the parent rule."
